# Can I use emacs f90-mode with fixed format?

Tags: emacs, fortran, fortran90

I'm updating some fortran 77 code to use fortran 90 constructs and emacs is my editor of choice.  Currently, the source is in fixed format and that isn't going to change any time soon (due to external constraints).  The two emacs major modes that I can choose from are `fortran-mode` which only highlights the syntax for fortran 77 constructs (It doesn't understand `module` or `contains`, etc. as keywords which I find pretty annoying, but it does understand fixed format -- correctly indenting the code where necessary).  The other major mode I could use is `f90-mode`, however, that gets the indentation all wrong which is also slightly annoying.  Is there any way to get the syntax highlighting from `f90-mode`, but the indentation structure used in `fortran-mode`?

Comment: It doesn't look like being possible. `fortran-mode` does not really understand F90+ features (although it says "... it is for editing Fortran77 or Fortran90 fixed source form") while `f90-mode` does not understand fixed source format. Both modes refer each other for features that they do not implement.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is indeed possible. Try adding the following to your config file:

```
(require 'f90)
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook 'f90-font-lock-2)
```

This is just following the solution provided on [emacs.stackexchange.com](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5288/editing-fortran90-in-a-fixed-format-mode?newreg=e243834485dc442baa012a2b14f59706), so thanks should flow to user [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353062/deprecated)!

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks to you (and deprecated) for finding this.  It's a bit late for it to be helpful to me, but I'm optimistic that the next user who comes along will be able to benefit from your find.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve some [fortran90](/questions/tagged/fortran90) like highlighting in `fortran-mode` by adding

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
 (lambda () (font-lock-add-keywords 'fortran-mode
 '(
      ("\\(CONTAINS\\)" 1 font-lock-keyword-face t )
      ("\\(USE\\)"      1 font-lock-keyword-face t )
 ))))
```

to your ~/.emacs (or ~/.emacs.d/init.el) file.

For a comprehensive solution some additional work with regular expressions would be needed. But with a few lines, you should be able to feel comfortable with your code. Different colors can be gained by using different faces:

```
font-lock-comment-face
font-lock-constant-face
font-lock-function-name-face 
font-lock-keyword-face
font-lock-type-face
font-lock-warning-face
```

Comment: yeah, this is pretty much what I ended up doing.  it was a pain though -- there's a lot of additional stuff to take into account... `select case`, closing subroutines with `end subroutine foo`, etc.