# How to highlight the Fortran fixed format continuation line symbol in Emacs, not in Fortran mode?

Tags: emacs, fortran

I am working on a f90 code but with fixed format files. So I made a specific major mode for this code files (in fact just the f90 mode using the fortran mode indentation functions). But it remains one thing I don't manage to handle: the coloration of the continuation line character in the 6th column. How to had that in my modified f90.el ?

Many thanks!

EDIT:

here is the derived mode:

```
(require 'fortran)

(define-derived-mode epx-mode f90-mode "EPX"
  (set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'fortran-indent-line)
  (set (make-local-variable 'indent-region-function)
       (lambda (start end)
         (let (fortran-blink-matching-if ; avoid blinking delay
               indent-region-function)
           (indent-region start end nil))))
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-syntactic-keywords)
     epx-font-lock-syntactic-keywords)
  )

(defvar epx-font-lock-syntactic-keywords nil
  "`font-lock-syntactic-keywords' for F90.
These get fixed-format comments fontified.")
(let ((comment-chars "cd\\*")       ; `d' for `debugging' comments
      )
  (setq epx-font-lock-syntactic-keywords
    ;; Fixed format comments.  (!-style handled normally.)
    (list
     (list (concat "^[" comment-chars "]") 0 '(11))
     (list (concat "^[^" comment-chars "\t\n]" ".\\{71\\}"
               "\\([^\n]+\\)")
           1 '(11))))
  )

(provide 'epx)
```

It change `indet-line-function` and `indent-region-function` to fortran version rather than f90. It also modify `font-lock-syntactic-keywords` to color the fixed format comments.

And an exemple code:

```
      module foo

* This is a fixed format comment                                                                                                                                              

      call bar(a, ! this is a f90 comment and a fortran splitted line                                                                                                         
     &     b)
 42   ! this is a label for a ugly goto                                                                                                                                       
      end module foo
```

I also just noticed that the labels are not highlighted too...

EDIT: Ok; I added the following to make it work:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'epx-mode
  '(("^ *\\([0-9]+\\)" . font-lock-constant-face)
    ("^ \\{5\\}\\([^ 0\n]\\)" 1 font-lock-string-face)
    ("^\t\\([1-9]\\)"         1 font-lock-string-face)))
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post a code example?

Comment: And the example of the modified el.f90. And describe what it does now.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319854/can-i-use-emacs-f90-mode-with-fixed-format?rq=1

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: Yes it is related but to my mind this post does not provide an effective solution

Comment: @VladimirF: I add the derived mode code

Comment: @janou195, I just tried this in Emacs 24.3. It appears to be working (as far as I can tell, without knowing Fortran). Can you give an example where you consider it to fail to color a line properly, and what you expected to see.

Comment: @Lindydancer: I use also emacs 24.3. I would like the "42" and the "&" in the given code to be colored. Try `M-x fortran-mode` to see what I would like for those two items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you inherit from `f90-mode` rather than `fortran-mode`. The two modes provide very difference sets of font-lock keywords, and it's only in `fortran-mode` that the `&` character and labels are highlighted.

*EDIT*: If you want f90 editing features, but still use the highlight of fortran mode, I guess you could add the following code (taken from fortran.el) to your code:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
     '((fortran-font-lock-keywords
        fortran-font-lock-keywords-1
        fortran-font-lock-keywords-2
        fortran-font-lock-keywords-3
        fortran-font-lock-keywords-4)
       nil t ((?/ . "$/") ("_$" . "w"))
       fortran-beginning-of-subprogram))
```

Alternatively, you could cherry pick individual font-lock rules from the fortran mode and add them to your mode using `font-lock-add-keywords`. (You could use [font-lock-studio](https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio) to step through font-lock rule by rule to see what effect they have.)

Comment: Yes, but this is what I want to do: to profit from the f90 mode features, with modofication to handle the fortran fixed format. So I fix indentation and fixed format commentary highligthing, but I cannot manage to handle `&` and labels...